# including handlers from different file

Tags: ansible, listener, handler

The handlers I have are not being run by the playbook or tasks

I have the following directory structur:

```
<project>
  - playbook.yml
  - <roles>
  -<handler>
     - main.yml
  -<meta>
  -<tasks>
      -main.yml
```

The problem is the handler is never called.

```
tasks/main.yml:

  - name: run task1
    command: run_task
    notify: "test me now"


handler/main.yml:

   - name: tested
     register: val1
     listen: "test me now"
```

The playbook just calls the task/main.yml and has host:all

Do I ned an include/import? I tried in playbook but it didn't help

Answer (score 8):

The play below works as expected

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: tasks/main.yml
    - meta: flush_handlers
    - debug:
        var: val1.stdout
  handlers:
    - import_tasks: handlers/main.yml
```

- *handlers* must be imported to be present when a *task* notifies a handler
- *tasks* may be included, or imported
- [*flush_handlers*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#ansible-builtin-meta-module-execute-ansible-actions) is needed if you want to use the variable *val1* in the playbook

A module is missing in *handler/main.yml*. This would cause:

> ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

Use some module in *handler/main.yml*. For example:

```yaml
- name: tested
  command: "echo 'running handler'"
  register: val1
  listen: "test me now"
```

Running such play gives

```yaml
  val1.stdout: running handler
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: tasks/main.yml
  handlers:
    - import_tasks: handlers/main.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat tasks/main.yml
- command: date
  register: result
  notify: test me now
```

```yaml
shell> cat handlers/main.yml
- name: test me now
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result.stdout }} Running handler."
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [include_tasks] *************************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp8/test-801/tasks/main.yml for localhost

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

RUNNING HANDLER [test me now] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Mon 25 Apr 2022 04:59:02 PM CEST Running handler.

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I guess the import part is in the main playbook where the roles are also imported?

Comment: However I only have imported the roles and handler in the main playbook, since there are 2 roles and each have a tasklist intheir own tasks/main.yml

Comment: _Importing_ "handlers" (which are basically tasks) does already execute them. Is there a way to include/import handlers without executing them on import?

Comment: This must be a misunderstanding. Importing handlers does not execute them. I added a simplified example. If you have a problem open a new question and include [mre].

Comment: @VladimirBotka I made a mistake when i was posting my answer. I don't know how i did get to hit edit on your answer. Sorry for the mistake. I rolled back.

Comment: I did roll back. It was right no. 6 does bring my answer 5 or 7 is your answer before i made the mistake. And thank you a lot. Sorry again.

Answer (score 3):

You should have the structure described in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html thus the directory should be called `handlers` (and not `handler`)

Answer (score 2):

## `Handlers folder` with `no imports` ❌

The question of wether `handlers` in `handlers`folder are loaded automatically. Like it's the case with roles.

> Answer: `NO`, they are not loaded automatically
>
> - you have to import them

- If you do

```yaml
- main.yml # playbook
- handlers
  - simple.yml
  - some.yml
```

And you don't import any handler. None will be loaded and available for notification.

## ✅ `Importing` handlers ✅

### The rules, behaviors and QA

- import them in `handlers:` of a playbook
- import them with `import_tasks` ✅

  - Not `include_tasks` ❌
  - Doc refs

    - [ref 1](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#includes-and-imports-in-handlers)
  - `import_tasks`

    - run at parsing time statically
    - Does resolve recursively all the tasks

      - make a one list
      - That list would be the list of handlers to add.
      - It's not a handler itself.

        - And it's name block, can't be referenced as a handler itself.
  - `include_tasks`

    - Is run at run time, dynamically
    - The block is the handler himself.
    - The tasks in the file will be loaded and executed dynamically once the handler (block) is notified and run.

      - All of them at once.
      - It's just bundling multiple tasks to run when the handler is notified. Instead of just a one module call.
- What about `flushing` them ?

  - Not needed (at least in ansible `2.15.4` Where i tested)

    - And the logic is

      - handlers run when they are `flushed`
      - `flush_handlers` is automatically run once the tasks finish.

        - generally if some tasks fail. All handlers will not run with the default at end `flushing`
      - `flush_handlers` give us control to flush at the time that we want.
      - when a task call notify

        - A handler is added to the list of handlers to flush. Or notified handlers.
        - Flushing is running that list of handlers (the `notified handlers` list)

#### More questions

- **Q:** Can we import the file with a name and notify that name to run all handlers inside

  - **A:** `No` => The import basically register the handler inside as if they were copied. (c++ and php, and conf `include`)

    - So basically when you import any file, or if a file that you import does in it's turn import other files. => `All will be resolved to a list of handlers` and you can refer any of the final resolved handlers by there names.

      - There is no notion of grouping handlers under another. But only a one list of all resolved handlers.
    - Assure you have unique names cross the files
    - That behavior started in `v2.8`
    - Doc ref

      - [Imports as handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.8.html#imports-as-handlers)

    > Beginning in version 2.8, a task cannot notify import_tasks or a static include that is specified in handlers.
    >
    > The goal of a static import is to act as a pre-processor, where the import is replaced by the tasks defined within the imported file. When using an import, a task can notify any of the named tasks within the imported file, but not the name of the import itself.
    >
    > To achieve the results of notifying a single name but running multiple handlers, utilize include_tasks, or listen Handlers: running operations on change.
- **Q:** What happens if two handlers in separate files have the same name ?

  - **A:** The first handler in the first loaded file would take precedence (**inverse** of last take precedence)

    - And clearly the best is to have unique names
- **Q:** Can we import roles within handlers ?

  - **A:** `NO` we can't, it's a limitation of handlers

    - Doc Ref: [Limitations](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#limitations)
- **Q:** Can we use `include_tasks` for handlers

  - **A:** `Depends`

    - The way `include_tasks:` works is that the name of the block, is a handler itself.

      - When you call that handler. You will execute all the tasks in `include_tasks` file
      - See next section, it does include doc ref too.

        - [Re-using tasks as handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#re-using-tasks-as-handlers)

### `include_tasks` (vs import)

```yaml
handlers:
  - name: Include Handler
    include_tasks: handlers/restart.yml
  - name: Import other handlers
    import_tasks: handlers/some.yml
  - name: Import another list of handlers
    import_tasks: handlers/another.yml
```

In the above

- The `import` one will register the tasks in the files as handlers.

  - `imports` are processed statically. At the parsing time.
  - `Import other handlers` or `Import another list of handlers` are not handlers themselves. But only the resolved handlers within the files ( `recursively` for all static imports)
- The `include` one is a handler itself (no resolving). There is no importing handlers in other files.

  - It's just a one handler.
  - The name is `Include Handler` above.
  - Dynamically when called, will load thee lists and run the tasks in it.

#### Why would you like to use `include`

- If you want to run more than one task, when a handler get notified.

  - Remember handlers are just tasks, that run on notification and after all tasks finish (default flushing point)
  - if  `flush_handlers` is used. Or multiple ones. At each `flush` the notified one will be run. And after task another default `flush_handlers` will be called as well

```yaml
# restarts.yml
- name: Restart apache
  ansible.builtin.service:
    name: apache
    state: restarted

- name: Restart mysql
  ansible.builtin.service:
    name: mysql
    state: restarted
```

- You would include that, if you want to run both tasks.

```yaml
- name: Trigger an included (dynamic) handler
  hosts: localhost
  handlers:
    - name: Restart services
      include_tasks: restarts.yml
  tasks:
    - command: "true"
      notify: Restart services
```

- We can see `Restart services` That's a handler itself. Not something that import. At it's run. It would run all tasks within the file.

  - `import` ones are not handlers themselves. But what is imported are. Resolving recursively. Till building the whole list.

#### Doc ref

- [Re-using tasks as handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#re-using-tasks-as-handlers)

## `Example` and running tests

Let's take this structure

```
- main.yml # playbook
  - handlers
    - simple.yml
    - simple2.yml
```

Handlers list

- `simple.yml`

```yaml
- name: "Test_it"
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "JUST SAYING HI - from simple 1"
- name: "Another handler"
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: "echo 'Hello la frindo'"
  changed_when: true
```

- `simple2.yml` a clone of `simple.yml`

  - with the difference of `- from simple 2`

    - so we can differentiate in a later test. (u'll see)
- The playbook `main.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: "Local testing"
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Notify simple handler
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "About to notify the simple handler"
      changed_when: true # will be notified on change
      # changed_when: false # will not if no change (no running)
      notify:
        - "Test_it"
        - "Another handler"

  handlers:
    - name: Simple handler
      import_tasks: "handlers/simple.yml"
```

### `Output` and conclusions

#### Run 1: importing `simple.yml` only

```yaml
PLAY [Setup bitwol server] ************************************************

TASK [Notify simple handler in handlers folder (without any import) - Are files in handlers folder loaded in the playbook (not role ????)] ***
changed: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "About to notify th e simple handler"
}

RUNNING HANDLER [Test_it] ************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "JUST SAYING HI - from simple 1"
}

RUNNING HANDLER [Another handler] ************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

> The `handlers` run `perfectly`

#### Run 2: Same thing but notifying task not changing

- We switch `change_when` to `false`

```yaml
changed_when: false
```

> The `handlers` `doesn't run`. And as expected when the tasks doesn't change. Nothing get notified.

#### Run 3: We `import` `simple2.yml` as well

```yaml
handlers:
  - name: Simple handler
    ansible.builtin.import_tasks: "handlers/simple.yml"
  - name: Simple handler 2
    ansible.builtin.import_tasks: "handlers/simple2.yml"
```

Output >

```yaml
PLAY [Setup bitwol server] ******************************

TASK [Notify simple handler in handlers folder (without any import) - Are files in handlers folder loaded in the playbook (not role ????)] ***
changed: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "About to notify th e simple handler"
}

RUNNING HANDLER [Test_it] ******************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "JUST SAYING HI - from simple 1"
}

RUNNING HANDLER [Another handler] ******************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

> You can see that in both `simple1.yml` and `simple2.yml` there is the same handler `Test_it`.
>
> - Only the one from the first file was run `simple1.yml`

#### Run 4: Keep all the same switch the order of simple1|2 imports

```yaml
handlers:
  - name: Simple handler 2
    ansible.builtin.import_tasks: "handlers/simple2.yml"
  - name: Simple handler
    ansible.builtin.import_tasks: "handlers/simple.yml"
```

Output >

```yaml
PLAY [Setup bitwol server] *****************************************************

TASK [Notify simple handler in handlers folder (without any import) - Are files in handlers folder loaded in the playbook (not role ????)] ***
changed: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "About to notify th e simple handler"
}

RUNNING HANDLER [Test_it] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "JUST SAYING HI - from simple 2"
}

RUNNING HANDLER [Another handler] **********************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************
localhost
```

- You can see that the `2` is the one that got to run.

> Conclusion if handlers with same name cross files are notified. Only the first one will execute.
>
> - Files import order first
> - Then Tasks in file order (in short the order after handlers list resolution)
> - You should always name the handlers uniquely

#### Run 5: No imports at all. Only `handlers` folder

- Remove the whole `hundlers:` block in the playbook

Output>

```yaml
PLAY [Setup bitwol server] ***********************************************

TASK [Notify simple handler in handlers folder (without any import) - Are files in handlers folder loaded in the playbook (not role ????)] ***
ERROR! The requested handler 'Test_it' was not found in either the main handlers list nor in the listening handlers list
```

- `No handlers were automatically loaded`

```yaml
ERROR! The requested handler 'Test_it' was not found in either the main handlers list nor in the listening handlers list
```

> Not like `roles`. You need to `import` and `no automatic loading`.

## `flush_handlers`

- Doc ref

  - [Controlling when handlers run](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#controlling-when-handlers-run)
- By default handlers run at the end after tasks finish
- `flush_handlers` allow us to run the already notified handlers. At the moment of `flush_handlers` call. Handlers will run. Than after them, the list of tasks to run continue.
- Handlers by default if tasks fail will not be run. If you want to force handlers to run at a specific time. For whatever reason. You can use `flush_handlers`

## When does handlers `run`

- Handlers triggered with `flush_handlers` or not

  - They do run when they `get notified`
  - `flush_handlers` does run already notified handlers
  - A handler will run, if get `notified`, and get notified if the `task` with `notify` block, does `change`

    - If a task does have `notify` block but doesn't `change` the `handler` will not run.
    - If your handlers are not running. Make sure the `notifying task` did `change`
    - with debug module, u'll need to use

```yaml
changed_when: true
```

```yaml
- name: Notify simple handler
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "About to notify the simple handler"
  changed_when: true
  # changed_when: false
  notify:
    - "Test_it"
    - "Another handler"
```

## Handlers `in roles`

- Doc ref

  - [Handlers in roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#handlers-in-roles)

We can add `.yml` files to `handlers` folder within the role folder. And they would automatically be loaded. No import needed.

## Issues and docs mentions

- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/59706

  - Doc ref linked
- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/61060

  - Add caution note in pitfall `PR`